# Is position: static identical to position: relative, with no other properties specified?

Tags: css, position, css-position

Is `position:static` equivalent to `position: relative` with none of the top, bottom, right, or left properties specified?

I though of this because an element with `postion: absolute` be relative to the first element that does NOT have `postion: static`. It seems arbitrary to make an element with `position: relative`, which will behave identically to a `position: static` if no other properties are used. Figured I might be missing something about `static` vs `relative`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **no**, both are different

`position: static;` means nothing but default position, you cannot use `top, right, bottom, left` unless and until you use `position: relative, absolute or fixed`, you need to use margins, moreover, `position: relative;` comes in real action when the child elements are positioned `absolute`, so that all elements can float inside the `position: relative;` div, if you just keep it static, they will go out of the document...

Take a look at the examples

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/xgAME/) (Keeping the div static and using top, left has no effect)

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/sBSPK/) (Making it `position: relative;` does effect top, left)

[Demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/xgAME/2/) (Keeping the parent div static, child will flow out if it's positioned `absolute`)

[Demo4](http://jsfiddle.net/xgAME/3/) (Child div positioned `absolute` will measure top, right, bottom, left from its parent div positioned `relative`)

This 1 is short and very simple but powerful [**tutorial video**](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/) to clear out your doubts

And a short article on [CSS positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: The first two demos are not applicable because you have `top` and `left` properties set, which are outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @BoltClock Just gave him a total demo, will be helpful not to the OP only but others too :)

Comment: i agree with @BoltClock, and for the element it self {position:static;} and {position:relative;} with no other entries seem to be equivalent as in this [fork]( http://jsfiddle.net/1mmzbjfp/1/). (just switch the div class from "relativeclass" to "staticclass" back and forth and run watching the div rendering that does not change.

Comment: i say that for it's clear the general behavior of static and relative, i was looking for some exception or hidden behaviors then i need this for a function that will append an absolute div to full cover some elements in my html (i don't know those elements in advance so they may be of any position) so i check if the element is not relative, absolute or fixed and in this case i change it to relative, so i can put my cover div with {position:absolute; top:0 ;left:0; right:0; bottom:0}... for that I was checking this Thread here. and find @Guffa reply replies better, if some others can confirm.

Answer (score 7):

Using `position: relative` without any positioning works the same as `position: static` for the element itself, but it makes difference for a child that has `position: absolute`.

An absolutely positioned element is placed relative to it's containing block, and the containing block is the closest parent that has a `position` setting other than `static`.